# How do I make a PHP form that submits to self?

Tags: php, html, forms

How do I make a self-posting/self-submitting form, i.e. a form that submits the results to itself, instead of submitting to another form?

Comment: You can also just leave the action off, and it defaults to the current page.

Comment: @Marvo There is an old bug that probably isn't too relevant today with WebKit. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/php-submit-to-self/5826792#5826792).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The proper way would be to use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` (in conjunction with `htmlspecialchars` to avoid possible exploits). You can also just skip the `action=` part empty, which is not W3C valid, but currently works in most (all?) browsers - the default is to submit to self if it's empty.

Here is an example form that takes a name and email, and then displays the values you have entered upon submit:

```
<?php if (!empty($_POST)): ?>
    Welcome, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>!<br>
    Your email is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>.<br>
<?php else: ?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Leaving action value empty is not W3C Valid. Just to notice. However it works well.

Comment: How do you do it so that it only runs `Welcome, <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]); ?>!<br>
    Your email is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>.<br>` and doesn't `echo` it like that?

Comment: Then what should we use here?

Comment: Just a warning here that PHP_SELF doesn't always work - I've just found this out as I had a form which was working with Joomla - when I turned on URL re-writing this PHP_SELF broke the form as according to Joomla PHP_SELF is "/index.php" (the site homepage) not "/contact-us".  I guess that's because index.php is calling it and I suppose there is some variable somewhere that includes the entire re-wrote URL?

Comment: Just found out that $_SERVER('REQUEST_URI') works much better and actually gets the url even if it's been rewrote.

Answer (score 11):

I guess , you means `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. And if so , you really shouldn't use it without sanitizing it first.  This leaves you open to XSS attacks.

The `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` condition should be above all the HTML output, and should contain a `header()` function with a redirect to current page again (only now , with some nice notice that "emails has been sent" .. or something ). For that you will have to use `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`.

And please. Stop using `$_REQUEST`. It too poses a security threat.

Answer (score 6):

That will only work if `register_globals` is on, and it *should never be on* (unless of course you are defining that variable somewhere else).

Try setting the `form`'s `action` attribute to `?`...

```
<form method="post" action="?">
   ...
</form>
```

You can also set it to be blank (`""`), but older WebKit versions had a [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7763).

Comment: @Damian I don't like to abuse the fragment identifier.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

`<form method="post" id="reg" name="reg" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"`

Works well :)

Answer (score 3):

Your submit button doesn't have a name. Add name="submit" to your submit button.

If you view source on the form in the browser, you'll see how it submits to self - the form's action attribute will contain the name of the current script - therefore when the form submits, it submits to itself. Edit for vanity sake!

Comment: Adding names to submit buttons is actually discouraged because they aren't submitted to the server in the first place and accessing forms by name in JavaScript is also deprecated.

Comment: @minitech I thought the `name` attribute was submitted to the server?

Comment: Don't down vote when you don't have the right response. Buttons most certainly are submitted in post back. Go test it!

Answer (score 3):

1. change
   `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />`
   to
   `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name='submit'/>`
2. change
   `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">`
   to
   `<form method="post" action="">`
3. It will perform the code in `if` only when it is submitted.
4. It will always show the form (html code).
5. what exactly is your question?

Comment: Adding names to submit buttons is actually discouraged because they aren't submitted to the server in the first place and accessing forms by name in JavaScript is also deprecated.

Comment: @minitech ? I actually see the submitted values of the input type=submit. What do you do so it is deprecated on your system?

Comment: @minitech Where does it say accessing forms by name is deprecated? Do you mean the old `forms.one.submit`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. @Itay Moav I missed the PHP code in post 1, can you edit your post so I can vote you back up again?