# HTML and PHP: Don't opening a new window in the browser

Tags: php, html

I have a file HTML with a lot of buttons, when I click a button, the action in the HTML is a reference to a php file. 
What can I do for don't open a new the page, I mean run the PHP file without opening it.

This is the form in my HTML

```
<form action="Controlador.php" method="POST">
    <p>He querido irme a dormir a las 8:00 en viernes</p>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="1" value="Vota" />
    <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Send the request via ajax. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: You should take a look at [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Comment: You can't do this purely in php, as php runs server-side.  You'd need to use a javascript/AJAX solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form without page reloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2866063/submit-form-without-page-reloading)

Answer (score 1):

see this [How do I make a PHP form that submits to self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self)

do not define separate action page, use same form page for action