# How to redirect to the same page for data insertion after form submit button in wordpress

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, redirect

I am new to Wordpress.I stuck in a problem where i want to Submit a form and also want data insertion in the wpdb in the same page.

Now i have two different pages one is for submit the form and another is to insert the data in the mysql db respectively.

I want to do the above process of form submission and data insertion in the same page.

Below are the codes:

**Below is the code for a form which will redirect to another page for data insertion.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3>Web Design On-line Requisition Form</h3>

<div>
  <form action="example.com?page_id=345" method="post" name="webForm">
    <label for="cname">Company/Institute Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname">

    <label for="pname">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname">

    <label for="webtype">Type of Website</label>
    <select id="webtype" name="webtype">
      <option value="Personal(Static Pages)">Personal(Static Pages)</option>
      <option value="Personal(Dynamic Page)">Personal(Dynamic Page)</option>
      <option value="Commercial(Static Pages)">Commercial(Static Pages)</option>
      <option value="Commercial(Dynamic Page)">Commercial(Dynamic Page)</option>
      <option value="Online Shopping Site">Online Shopping Site</option>
      <option value="Educational Site">Educational Site</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <label for="contact">Contact No.</label>
    <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact">
    <label for="email">Email ID</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
    <label for="pappdate">Preferred Appointment Date</label>
    <input type="date" name="pappdate">

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is another page where i wrote the code for data insertion to the mysql using wpdb**

```
[insert_php]
$cname=$_POST['cname'];
$pname=$_POST['pname'];
$webtype=$_POST['webtype'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$pappdate=$_POST['pappdate'];
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->insert( 
    'sometable', 
    array( 
   'cname' => $cname,
   'pname' => $pname,
   'webtype' => $webtype,
   'contact' => $contact,
   'email' => $email,
   'address' => $address,
   'pappdate' => $pappdate
        ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%s', 
                '%s', 
'%s', 
'%s', 
'%s', 
'%s' 
    ) 
);



[/insert_php]
```

Comment: Use `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` in `action`
Refer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self)

Comment: Actually i figured it out. $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] wil not work here in wordpress.If I left the form action blank means form action="" then it worked.But i dont know whether it is the correct procedure or not.