# How to get the sucess message in the same page after submitting the contact form?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have created the contact form using HTML and PHP. Also, the mail is coming correctly to mail id. But after the success message, it is redirecting to the `form.php` page can someone please help me. It is my first time trying to build a website.

Here is my code for contact form:

```
<form method="post" action="form.php">
    <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

here is my `form.php` :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: agriindiaexp.com'; 
$to = 'shridhar.kagi@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Email Inquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       $success = "Message successfully sent";
    } else {
        $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
    }
}
?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Check: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self)

Comment: If you want it without page refresh then check [http://www.codingcage.com/2015/06/submit-php-form-without-page-refresh-jquery-ajax.html](http://www.codingcage.com/2015/06/submit-php-form-without-page-refresh-jquery-ajax.html)

Comment: or `<form method="post" action="/">` and add your form request php code to this page

Comment: I want it in the same page.

Comment: @bhavya gvn after success message you want to redirect it to same page?or another page?

Comment: @Shanu k k i want it to redirect it to the same page

Comment: please <form method="post" action=" " > or <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">try this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this way . try to send mail from an ajax . Please write your code like below

javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function sendEnquiryform(){
        var name=$('#name').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
        var message=$('#message').val();
        $.post("send_mail.php",'name='+name+'&email='+email'&message='+message,function(result,status,xhr) {
                if( status.toLowerCase()=="error".toLowerCase() )
                { alert("An Error Occurred.."); }
                else { 
                    //alert(result);
                    $('#sucessMessage').html(result);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){ alert("something went wrong. Please try again") });
    }
</script>
```

Your html

```
<form method="post" name="FrmEnquiry" id="FrmEnquiry" action="" onsubmit="sendEnquiryform();">
    <input name="name" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

<span id="sucessMessage"> </span>
```

send_mail.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: agriindiaexp.com'; 
    $to = 'shridhar.kagi@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Email Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
           $success = "Message successfully sent";
        } else {
            $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
        }
    }
?>
```

this will display your message in your page.Please try this. This is working fine in my case.

Answer (score 3):

You could post the form to the same page and check for a success message there, like this.

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: agriindiaexp.com'; 
    $to = 'shridhar.kagi@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Email Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       $success = "Message successfully sent";
    } else {
        $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
    }
}
?>

...other html....

<div id="message"><?php if(isset($success)){ echo $success; } ?></div>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input name="name" required="required" placeholder="Your Name">
    <input name="email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="Your Email">

    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    <textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5" required="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <div class="submit">
        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>

...other html....
```

Answer (score 0):

getting the error in java script.

```
function sendEnquiryform(){
        var fname=$('#fname').val();
        var email=$('#email').val();
        var pd=$('#pd').val();
        var pg=$('#pg').val();
        var ced=$('#ced').val();
        var score=$('#score').val();
        var message=$('#message').val();
        $.post("mail.php",'fname='+name+'&email='+email' +'&pd='+pd' +'&pg='+pg' +'&ced='+ced' +'&score='+score'&message='+message,function(result,status,xhr) } 
                if( status.toLowerCase()=="error".toLowerCase() )
                { alert("An Error Occurred.."); } 
                else { 
                    //alert(result);
                    $('#sucessMessage').html(result);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){ alert("something went wrong. Please try again") });
    }
```

Comment: Is this answer or question that you mentioned here?

Comment: This is questions i am facing issue

Answer (score 0):

Using the mail.php on the same page where the form is could do the magic. the following code did the magic.

```
<?php

$from = '';
$sendTo = 'email@email.com';
$subject = 'New message from contact form';
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email', 'subject' => 'Subject', 'message' => 'Message');

$okMessage = 'Thank you for your message. I will write back soon.';
$errorMessage = 'There is an error while sending message. Please try again later.';

try {if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=====\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
       if (isset($fields[$key])) {
         $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
       }
    }
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
 'From: ' . $from,
 'Reply-To: ' . $from,
 'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $e->getMessage());
}
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
 $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 echo $encoded;
} else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}


?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
    $(function () {
  $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
   if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    var url = "contact.php";

    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: url,
     data: $(this).serialize(),
     success: function (data) {
      var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
      var messageText = data.message;
      var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"> 
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times; 
</button>' + messageText + '</div>';
       if (messageAlert && messageText) {
       $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
       $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
      }
     }
    });
    return false;

   }
  })
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2">
   <h1>CONTACT FORM</h1><hr>
   <p class="lead">By filling out the contact form; You may have information about us and current news.</p>
   <form id="contact-form" method="post"  role="form" novalidate="true">
   <div class="messages"></div>
   <div class="controls">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="form_name">Full Name *</label>
        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please fill the name field *" required="required" data-error="You must fill the name field">
        <div class="help-block with-errors alert-danger"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="form_email">E-mail *</label>
       <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please fill the email field *" required="required" data-error="You must fill the email field">
        <div class="help-block with-errors alert-danger"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="form_subject">Subject *</label>
       <input id="form_subject" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Please fill the subject field *" required="required" data-error="You must fill the subject field">
        <div class="help-block with-errors alert-danger"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
      </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
      <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Please fill the message field *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="You must fill the message field"></textarea>
       <div class="help-block with-errors alert-danger"></div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Submit">
      <p class="text-muted" style="padding-top: 5px;"><strong>*</strong>This field must be fill.</p>
      </div><!-- controls all end -->
     </form><!-- form all end -->
    </div><!-- col-xl-8 offset-xl-2 end -->
   </div><!-- row all end -->
 </div><!-- container all end -->

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code

```
<?php

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: agriindiaexp.com'; 
    $to = 'shridhar.kagi@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'Email Inquiry';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
       $success = "Message successfully sent";
    } else {
        $success = "Message Sending Failed, try again";
    }

    echo $success;
}
?>
```