# How to run a PHP function due to a button click (with button 'data' passed)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, database

I know that AJAX could solve my issue. I need help how I can solve it in my specific case however. I manage some sortiment items on a page, they get displayed with a PHP script (checks the database, if the item is available, and if so, it gets displayed). I now want an admin page where I can kind of "toggle" via a sortiment table to display or not display an item (set it as available or non available.

What I need is: if the button is clicked, I would like to start a php-skript. There should be an value passed to that script (the button id). The script itself should open an SQL connection, change a DB value based on the passed ID of the button. Then close the connection. Optionally also refresh the table (or one value) from where the button was clicked.

Can someone help me, at least telling me what I need to do this? (jQuery, Ajax?). The passing of the ID would be important, else I'd need to do function for every button.

An table entry looks like this:

````html
<tr>
    <td>Himbeerhonig</td>
    <td id="himbeerhonig">Ja</td>
    <td><button type="button" id="himbeerhonig" onclick="function()">press me to execute function</button></td>
</tr>```

(possible PHP pseudocode)
open SQL connection
   look for database entry based on the passed ID
   change the value of the found entry (!currentValue)
close SQL connection

*optionally*
refresh the <td id="himbeerhonig"> with the updated value.
````

I appreciate any help very much! Just need some hints as to how to do it properly. It's just a concept that currenty is hard to grasp for me so far.

Comment: You should find your answer in this post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- If you want to do this with ajax (without browser refresh), you should create a separate `php` file, and put your php scripts in there. it's called `api` (api has special format for output, so search `create api in php` if you want to do this). then on javascript, you should do an `ajax` call to that php address, on `onclick` event of button. and then javascript will return data and you can create elements based on that data.

2- however you can do this without ajax(it will refresh browser). just write your inline phps as you wrote :

```
<html>
<!-- your html codes-->
<?php
  if($_GET['buttonClicked']){
  //put your php codes here to run when button clicked
  ?>
    <!-- you can even put html here, even it can be on php loop. -->
  <?
  }
<!-- your html codes-->

<!-- turn your button to a form-->
<form action="/" method="get">
  <input name="buttonClicked" hidden value='1'>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
```

it's as easy as this. when button clicked, a get request will send to current page, and php will handle it, for example it will render additional html elements to the page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try it without ajax first and maybe do the ajax way later on. Again, thank you for the easy to understand explanation. :)

Comment: @wftico your welcome. however i didn't test code, i just wanted to describe the approach. so don't panic if you get syntax error or whatever. here is more codes that you can use for both approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738329/how-to-call-a-php-function-on-the-click-of-a-button

Comment: The non Ajax solution worked just fine for me. Sure, the page reload actually really is annoying. But it was just for a test project anyway. When I've got the time I'll try the REST API solution. :)

Comment: @wftico YES!!! first time on history i manually wrote code that runs without errors :p just kidding, glad it helped :D