# How to redirect on the same page after submitting form in modal?

Tags: database, forms

I have made one file name as index.php
when I open that first it will be shown a form in modal. After filling that form and when i click on submit i want to redirect on the same page and also store data in database.

Comment: The answer you're looking for is answered on another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a PHP form that submits to self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826784/how-do-i-make-a-php-form-that-submits-to-self)

Answer (score 0):

Its easy job after filling the form you can just include this php code:

```
<?php
header( "Location: index.php" );
exit ;
?>
```

for more information you can use the link below or ask in comments:
https://www.thesitewizard.com/php/how-to-redirect-to-another-web-page.shtml

[image]